What is the type hint for socket?
Suppose I'm writing a function that takes a socket as a parameter. How should I type hint it properly?
def read_socket(socket: ???):
    ....


The first (and only) non-exception class mentioned on the page you link to is socket.

You're right. Can't believe that I missed it...

Note for those who are generally curious: you can (most of the time) use an object's class as a type hint

The type is just socket.socket.
import socket

def f(sock: socket.socket): ...


In general, you can get the class of the object with one of these methods.

print(type(obj))
help(obj)
print(obj.__class__)

This doesn't always work though, because sometimes you don't have direct access to the namespace of the class.
